# Python Dataframe: Using astype to change column type fails

Tags: python, dataframe

I have been using astype to change the type of the columns for a while. However, I run into an unexpected result today. I have a column named `modularity_class`, and I am trying to convert it from float to int and assign to a new column

```
communities_to_analyze['modularity'] = communities_to_analyze['modularity_class'].astype(int)
```

However, this gives me interesting result

```
>>print(communities_to_analyze['modularity'][0])
94
>>print(communities_to_analyze.iloc[0]['modularity'])
94.0
```

This looks so ridiculous. I am using pandas 1.1.1, and this has never happened to me before. I was wondering if anyone has run into the same problem before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
communities_to_analyze.iloc[0]['modularity']
```

Here you first access the first row of your data frame. It is converted to a pandas series. If there is a float number somewhere in the row every value is converted to float. Thus, if you then access the index 'modularity' of your pandas series it will return a float and not integer.

```
communities_to_analyze['modularity'][0])
```

Here you do it the other way round. First, select the column 'modularity'. The values remain integer because there is no float in this column.
Thus, if you then access the first value it will return an integer.

Comment: Thank you! This makes a lot of sense! When I'm checking the type, it suggests that communities_to_analyze.iloc[0].dtype is float64.

Comment: Do you happen to know if there is anyway that we can assign a type for the whole dataframe to solve this problem? So that when we access by row, the int will still be int? I know maybe adding a column of string or list will help, but there might be a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: If your dataframe only contains integers you could convert everything all columns: df = df.astype(int)

Answer (score 0):

`df['modularity_class'][0]` will returns the content of one cell of the dataframe, in this case the string `'94.0'`. This is now returning a `str` object that doesn't have this function.You can convert it like below:

```
communities_to_analyze['modularity'] = int(communities_to_analyze['modularity_class'])
```

Comment: I'm not sure about this. It doesn't seem like int can be applied to a pandas series, but thanks for suggesting.

Comment: Just try it. Works!